# Can I undo multiple times in nvi and/or the original vi?

Tags: undo-redo, nvi, original-vi

Sometimes I'm on a system without Vim, and use the default `nvi` (BSD systems)
or the original `vi` (Arch Linux).

There are quite a few differences, but the largest annoyance is that I can undo
*only* my last operation. Pressing <kbd>u</kbd> the second time works are a
"redo".

Is there some way to get this working?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From [`nvi(1)`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/ex.1?query=vi):

```
 u       Undo the last change made to the file.  If repeated, the u command
         alternates between these two states.  The . command, when used
         immediately after u, causes the change log to be rolled forward or
         backward, depending on the action of the u command.
```

So press <kbd>u</kbd>, and then keep pressing <kbd>.</kbd> for more undo; If you press <kbd>u</kbd> again, it will 'reverse' direction and pressing <kbd>.</kbd> will be a redo.

I never knew about this until yesterday; and thought it was somehow a new feature, but it seems
like it has [worked like this since at least nvi 1.79 from 1996](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/59cc89c2c2e686da3bdab2d5cfac4f33462d29fe/contrib/nvi/docs/help).

This *doesn't* work in the [**original vi**](http://ex-vi.cvs.sourceforge.net/);
where the undo is documented as:

```
   u      Undoes the last change made to the current buffer.  If repeated,
          will alternate  between  these  two  states,  thus  is  its  own
          inverse.  When  used after an insert which inserted text on more
          than one line, the lines are saved in the numeric named  buffers
          (3.5).
```

Which is really a complicated way of saying that pressing <kbd>u</kbd> again
will redo your changes.

Which is also what Vim's `:help undo` says (and why I assumed it also wouldn't
work in `nvi`):

```
 u                       Undo [count] changes.  {Vi: only one level}
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing the original `vi` has to multiple undo (aside from `U` which can revert multiple changes within a single line) is the numbered registers,
which hold the nine most recent changes or deletions.

If you put from a numbered register, subsequent dot commands
will increment that register when it repeats the command.

E.g. with the following text, with the cursor line indicated with `>`,

```
  aaaa
> bbbb
  cccc
  dddd
  eeee
```

the command `dd..` will result in:

```
  aaaa
> eeee
```

If you then type `"1P`, vi will put the most recent deletion
from register `"1`:

```
  aaaa
> dddd
  eeee
```

Hitting `.` will put the contents of the next most recent
register, by doing `"2P`, and hitting `.` again will put
the contents of register `"3`.

So, in short, `"P..` will put back all the text you deleted,
leaving you with

```
  aaaa
> bbbb
  cccc
  dddd
  eeee
```

Not brilliant, but better than nothing! More usefully you
can use it at the beginning or end of the buffer to quickly
inspect what's in your numbered registers. Then you can
easily delete what you don't need.

It's documented in
vim under `:help redo-register`.

Answer (score -1):

Using the original vi, hit [n]u to go back n steps.
To progressively go back step by step...

- hit [n]u to go back n steps
- then hit [n]u to redo n steps
- then hit [n+1]u to go back [n+1] steps
- etc

Comment: I have [something close to the original vi](http://ex-vi.sourceforge.net/), and it doesn't seem to go back n steps.

Comment: Agreed. Original Vi can revert only a single change with `u`, or restore a single line to how it was before you started editing it with `U`.